# Maven shade and assembly plugins resulting in stack overflow

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a reasonably simply RESTEasy client application that I have tried to compile into a self contained JAR file using both the Maven Shade and Assembly plugins. Maven will package the application successfully, and it will launch OK, but eventually I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.ASCII.getType(ASCII.java:199)
    at java.util.regex.ASCII.isType(ASCII.java:203)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ctype.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:3832)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4125)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4502)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3408)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1199)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:618)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2517)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2845)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:384)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:319)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:442)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.copyFromError(BaseClientResponse.java:94)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure.<init>(ClientResponseFailure.java:32)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:488)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:479)
```

The call stack after org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:384) is repeated over and over until the memory is exhausted.

My code is not the problem. The application runs fine when it is packaged using the [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html).

My code does rely on regex named groups (which rely on Java 1.7), but I can confirm that Maven and the application itself are compiled and run using the correct JDK.

Can anyone explain how a self contained JAR file can cause a stack overflow like this.

Comment: Does the self-contained JAR have anything in `META-INF/services`?

Comment: Without your pom configuration for maven-shade no expression is possible..

Comment: Is this still of interest. If so, please post the declaration of your shade-plugin in your pom.xml

Comment: Post your `dependency:tree`.